# Avoiding words to break up

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

I have a problem with my layout (HTML / CSS). My words will break to a second line creating a horrible effect.

I have tried `word-break: break-word` in my CSS but doesn't work.

**My ERB**

```
 <%= link_to tag_path(tag), class: "line-height" do %>
       <span class="spot_tag"> # <%= "#{tag}" %> </span>
 <% end %>
```

**MY CSS**

```
     .spot_tag {
    margin-right: 5px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #48b581;
    color: #ebfff5;
    border: 1px solid #34c17e;  
    font-weight: 700;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    background-color: #29cf9a;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    border-radius: 35px;
    font-size: 13px;
    background: #4be59b; /* Old browsers */
}
```

**PROBLEM**

[image: Prob with tags]

Answer (score 2):

Display the span as an inline-block. That way it will stick together.

```
.spot_tag {
    margin-right: 5px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #48b581;
    color: #ebfff5;
    border: 1px solid #34c17e;  
    font-weight: 700;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    background-color: #29cf9a;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    border-radius: 35px;
    font-size: 13px;
    background: #4be59b; /* Old browsers */
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/77a7emkx/).

Answer (score 0):

`word-break: break-word` will break words according to their rule. # is not part of the word.

You should use `word-break:keep-all`

Comment: Still wont work :( , I try adding that property to the link / span and didnt do anything. Weird.

Comment: @Gibson I see that there is a space between # and the word. This is why.

Comment: Looks as if the space is the problem

Comment: Because space is introducing a new word. Try `white-space: wrap;`

Comment: Fixed by only removing the space, no white-space needed! Thanks